# how to combine 2 NSDictionary Contain array to one NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

i have 2 dictionary data in 2 different array i want to join the data in to one array

NSDictionary 1

```
[{ image="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOAAAADhCAMAAADmr0l2AAAAkFBMVEX/AAD/9vb/+/v/19f/bW3/0ND/5eX/Kyv/+fn/3Nz/q6v/rq7/qKj/oqL/Hh7/iYn/7u7/w8P/nZ3/Njb/ysr/8/P/trb/vr7/QkL/lJT/Z2f/6ur/WVn/Pj7/GRn/fn7/c3P/jIz/U1P/VVX/TU3/X1KCj/v7l5f/R0f/goL/EhL/Y2P/eHj/
},
{ image = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOAAAADhCAMAAADmr0l2AAAAkFBMVEX/AAD/9vb/+/v/19f/bW3/0ND/5eX/Kyv/+fn/3Nz/q6v/rq7/qKj/oqL/Hh7/iYn/7u7/w8P/nZ3/Njb/ysr/8/P/trb/vr7/QkL/lJT/Z2f/6ur/WVn/Pj7/GRn/fn7/c3P/jIz/U1P/VVX/TU3/X1KCj/v7l5f/R0f/goL/EhL/Y2P/eHj/}]
```

NSDictionary 2

```
[ {name = "IMG_0006.PNG";
},
{name = "IMG_0004.PNG";
}]
```

i want to combain these 2 into one array
i tried this code

```
        for (NSDictionary* dict1 in finalArrayImageName) {
        for (NSDictionary* dict2 in imageFinal) {
            NSMutableDictionary* dict = [dict1 mutableCopy];
            [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
            [imageFinalEncryption addObject: dict];
         break;
        }
    }
```

but the images coming is same for every image

i need the array like this

```
array =[{image= image1,
name="IMG_0006.PNG"},
{image= image2;
name = "IMG_0004.PNG";
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of nested for loops you are using

What you have to do is use single loop & get object by index

**NOTE** : You must have same number of element in both array !! , Otherwise app will be crashed

Here is example

```
for (int i = 0;i < finalArrayImageName.count;i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [finalArrayImageName[i] mutableCopy];
    [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:imageFinal[i]];

    [imageFinalEncryption addObject:dict]'

}
```

Hope it is helpful to you